# Not a class, namespace or enumeration?

Tags: c++, cyclic-dependency

My teacher got me a code to study and I can't figure out when I `typedef` the map (as i commented in the code) it works fine but when I define without `typedef` it doesn't seems to work. If someone could be kind to explain I would be grateful! I read something about "cyclic dependency" but not sure if it's the case here.

```
int main (){

    map <string, string> ri; // typedef map<string, string> maps;
    //maps ri;
    ri.insert(pair<string, string>{"Smoljan", "Dragan"});
    ri.insert(pair<string, string>{"Smolver", "Tina"});
    ri.insert(pair<string, string>{"Mirkovic", "Sonja"});

    string in;
    cout<<"Input:";
    cin>>in;

    string high(in);
    high.back()++;

    auto low = ri.lower_bound(in);

    /*(maps)*/ ri::key_compare comp;  //<----- here is the error

    //....
}
```

Comment: I don't see a `typedef` and `ri` is an object.

Comment: so, can you tell me what "ri::key_compare comp" does?

Comment: It does not compile because `ri` does not work with `::`, so it effectively does nothing.

Comment: so only class type works with :: ?

Comment: No, all scope identifiers, which also include namespaces and classes. From a purely logical point of view, how should an object work as a scope?

Comment: object of keycompare is  the same type as the object ri, so map<string, string>, now i got it =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, cause is clear: *ri is not a class, namespace or enumeration*. It is an object.

What you need is to place before semicolons what you put with typedef: *type name*.

```
map <string, string>::key_compare comp;
```

or (C++11)

```
decltype(ri)::key_compare comp;
```